# Making php (WordPress) code DRY which has slight variations

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

In my single-work.php I have some code with slight variations that I feel could be more DRY. When there are only slight variations like this is it ok to repeat part of the code? Or is there another way to write parts of this?

```
// Advanced Custom Fields

// Grid images or videos
$grid_image_1       = get_field('image_1');
$grid_image_2       = get_field('image_2');
$grid_image_3       = get_field('image_3');
$grid_image_4       = get_field('image_4');
$grid_image_5       = get_field('image_5');


// Video embeds
$image_1_video      = get_field('image_1_do_you_wish_to_add_a_video');
$video_embed_code_1 = get_field('video_embed_code_1');

$image_2_video      = get_field('image_2_do_you_wish_to_add_a_video');
$video_embed_code_2 = get_field('video_embed_code_2');

$image_3_video      = get_field('image_3_do_you_wish_to_add_a_video');
$video_embed_code_3 = get_field('video_embed_code_3');

$image_4_video      = get_field('image_4_do_you_wish_to_add_a_video');
$video_embed_code_4 = get_field('video_embed_code_4');

$image_5_video      = get_field('image_5_do_you_wish_to_add_a_video');
$video_embed_code_5 = get_field('video_embed_code_5');


// General
$about              = get_field('about');
$subtitle           = get_field('subtitle');


get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'carousel' );

?>

<!-- Page Content -->
<!-- Work -->
<section id="our-work">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 section-title">
                <h3><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>
            </div><!-- title -->
        </div><!-- row -->
        <div class="work-images">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">

                    <?php if( $image_1_video == "Yes" ): ?>
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#">
                            <img src="<?php echo $grid_image_1['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $grid_image_1['alt']; ?>">
                        </a>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $grid_image_1['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $grid_image_1['alt']; ?>">
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div><!-- col -->
                <div class="col-sm-4">

                    <?php if( $image_2_video == "Yes" ): ?>
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" href="#">
                            <img src="<?php echo $grid_image_2['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $grid_image_2['alt']; ?>">
                        </a>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $grid_image_2['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $grid_image_2['alt']; ?>">
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div><!-- col -->
                <div class="col-sm-4">

                    <?php if( $image_3_video == "Yes" ): ?>
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" href="#">
                            <img src="<?php echo $grid_image_3['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $grid_image_3['alt']; ?>">
                        </a>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $grid_image_3['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $grid_image_3['alt']; ?>">
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div><!-- col -->
            </div><!-- row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">

                    <?php if( $image_4_video == "Yes" ): ?>
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" href="#">
                            <img src="<?php echo $grid_image_4['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $grid_image_4['alt']; ?>">
                        </a>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $grid_image_4['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $grid_image_4['alt']; ?>">
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div><!-- col -->
                <div class="col-sm-4">

                    <?php if( $image_5_video == "Yes" ): ?>
                        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" href="#">
                            <img src="<?php echo $grid_image_5['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $grid_image_5['alt']; ?>">
                        </a>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $grid_image_5['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $grid_image_5['alt']; ?>">
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div><!-- col -->
            </div><!-- row -->
        </div><!-- work images -->
    </div><!-- container -->
</section><!-- work -->


<section id="work-text">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <p><?php echo $about ?></p>
            </div><!-- col -->
        </div><!-- row -->
    </div><!-- container -->
</section><!-- work -->


<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Video</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe src=" <?php echo $video_embed_code_1; ?>" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 2 -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Video</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe src=" <?php echo $video_embed_code_1; ?>" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 3 -->
<div id="myModal3" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Video</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe src=" <?php echo $video_embed_code_3; ?>" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 4 -->
<div id="myModal4" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Video</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe src=" <?php echo $video_embed_code_4; ?>" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 5 -->
<div id="myModal5" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Video</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe src=" <?php echo $video_embed_code_5; ?>" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>


<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'otherwork' ); ?>


<?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'instagram' ); ?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: When you have variables named `$grid_image_1`, `$grid_image_2`, `$grid_image_3`, you know you can just make that in an array. So `$grid_image = array();` and that array will hold all values that you can generate in a forloop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instinct to make this code more DRY is spot-on. Here's a partial solution demonstrating how you should approach the problem:

```
<?php
$numVideos = 5;

$grid_image_array       = array();
$image_video_array      = array();
$video_embed_code_array = array();

for ($i = 1; $i <= $numVideos; $i++) {
    $grid_image_array[$i]       = get_field('image_' . $i);
    $image_video_array[$i]      = get_field('image_' . $i . '_do_you_wish_to_add_a_video');
    $video_embed_code_array[$i] = get_field('video_embed_code_' . $i);
}

?>
<!-- I snipped out some of your HTML for brevity -->
<?php for ($i = 1; $i <= $numVideos; $i++): ?>    
    <div id="myModal<?= $i ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">    
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Video</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <iframe src=" <?php echo $video_embed_code_array[$i]; ?>" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>    
<?php endfor; ?>
```